# Mongoose issue: some fields not getting updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a mongo collection like this. I see that some fields in my collection get updated whereas others don't. Is there an issue in this code someone can point to me? I would be happy to add more details as needed.

```
exports.updateIngredientByName = function (req, res) {
  mongoose.model('BaseIngredientUtensil').update({"name": req.body.name},req.body )
  .exec(function (err, iData) {
    console.log(err);
    if(err){
      console.log('GET request didn\'t work');
    }else {
      res.format({
         json: function () {
             res.json(iData);
         }
      });
    }
  });
```

req.body contains all the fields of the object in the collection. Fields like name (string), subtype (string) get updated whereas type, which is also a string type does not seem to get updated.

Comment: what comes in req.body? What is already stored? Which fields do not get updated?

Comment: Are all the fields declared in the mongoose shema schema?

Comment: Added details in the question.

Comment: Could you give the following a try: `mongoose.model('BaseIngredientUtensil').collection.update({"name": req.body.name},req.body )`? With the collection property we access the raw mongodb driver. We might be able to tell if the problem is with Mongoose or with the query.

Comment: Sure I would try that and report the findings here. Thanks for your input.